# Why Carbon toDatetimeString is not returning the expected format?

Tags: php, php-carbon

From the documentation I see:

```
 echo $dt->toDateTimeString();                      // 1975-12-25 14:15:16
```

But Actually if I dump my execution I get:

```
$now = Carbon::now()->toDayDateTimeString();
dump($now); //Mon, Oct 2, 2017 12:49 PM
```

I need to :

```
$now = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

in order to get :

```
dump($now); //2017-10-02 12:49:06
```

What am I missing?

Comment: what you missed is that you called toDayDateTimeString (notice the "Day" part)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try resetting string format to default:

`Carbon::resetToStringFormat()`

then `Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()` should give you what you are looking for.

From: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-formatting